# "Attempt to read a row while there is no result set associated with the statement" on Linux server but no error on Windows computer

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using `mysqli` to connect to a MySQL database with PHP.

As I am programming on a windows computer with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

While coding I get neither errors nor warnings. But on the server I get

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message
>   'Attempt to read a row while there is no result set associated with the statement'

I think this is a little bit strange.

The error is thrown, if you call `mysqli_stmt::fetch()` on a statment that provides no results, e.g. after executing an insert, update or delete query, or if you already called `mysqli_stmt::free_result()`.

There was a part of my code that was messed up and I fixed it already.

But my question is, why is this error not thrown on my development platform?
Is there an option in the php.ini or somewhere I have to set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now tested some settings and the result is:

If you use "MySQL Client Library" instead of ["MySQL Native Driver"](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) you get the error described in the question. I don't know, why the server were not using mysqlnd, as it is default since PHP 5.4.0 and there seams to be no reason to not use it but some advantages, so I changed it.

But however, one should not try to fetch results from an insert, update or delete query or after freeing the result. This is just senseless.